# Escaping the single quote character

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In the code below, I'm building a string in my controller. In this string I use the single quote character. I need to protect this character before rendering it. First, I try something like **L\'affaire** but it doesn't work (because the quote character is already used in my helper, see below). I succeed with **L& # 3 9;affaire** (escape character for single quote, without spaces) but maybe there is a better way to proceed?

In my controller, I prepare a string like this:

```
        var builderAnchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        builderAnchor.MergeAttribute("href", "#");
        builderAnchor.InnerHtml = "Annuler";

        var builderText = new StringBuilder();
        builderText.Append("L&#39;affaire " + affaire.IdAffaire + " a été supprimée. ");
        builderText.Append(builderAnchor);

        sessionWrapper.Notification = new HtmlString(builderText.ToString());
```

Next, I have a helper called from a view like this:

```
    public static IHtmlString ShowNotification(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        //...
        returnedValue = "yellowNotification('" + helper.Encode(sessionWrapper.Notification) + "')";


        return new HtmlString(returnedValue);
    }
```

Finally, all of this stuff produce the html like below:

```
yellowNotification('L'affaire 12345 a été supprimée');
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
public static IHtmlString ShowNotification(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    //...
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var value = serializer.Serialize(sessionWrapper.Notification);
    returnedValue = string.Format("yellowNotification({0})", value);
    return new HtmlString(returnedValue);
}
```

This will ensure that no matter what characters the Notification string contains it will be properly passed to the `yellowNotification` function.

Also I don't quite understand what's the relation of the first code snippet you have shown to the second but what is sure that such code has no place in a controller.

Comment: I placed this code in an action controller because it is a Delete action where an affair is deleted and a notification is generated. This notification will be showed when the next view will be showed. It is the same scenario like Gmail: you can delete a message in Gmail and after the deleting, a notification is displayed at the top of the page. Do you see what I mean? I think I had to manage this kind of thing in my delete action controller...

Comment: @Bronzato I see what you mean, but handling HTML is not the responsibility of the controller. His responsibility is to delete the item and send to the view a view model probably containing the id of this item. It is then the responsibility of this view to format and show the notification (maybe through the use of an HTML helper or whatever).

Comment: you are absolutely right. I refactor my controller & view in that way. Thank you very much for your help.